# VBA workbook object giving "Subscript Out of range Error"

Tags: vba, excel, range, out

I'm trying to use below code
PrintWB has following value `"C:\Users\jarora\Desktop\Master Test Sheet.xlsx"`

```
PrintWB = .Cells(i, 1) & "\" & .Cells(i, 2)
Workbooks(PrintWB).Sheets(Sheetname).Printout From:=Frompage, To:=Topage
```

Above line is giving me error 'Subscript Out of range Error' when referencing Workbook object.

I get the following error on the above line when referencing the Workbook object:

> Subscript Out of Range Error

Any help will be appreciated immensely since this is my last piece of puzzle I'm trying to put together.

Comment: Is your workbook `Master Test Sheet.xlsx` open? Because `Workbooks()` is a `collection` of all the currently open workbooks in excel. In other words, if that workbook isn't open, it isn't in the `Workbooks()` collection. If it is open, then you can either call on it 1 of 2 ways. By index or by name. Index is a number, so 1 would be the first opened book. Name would be "Master Test Sheet.xlsx". Not the entire address.

Comment: How do you know it isn't `.Sheets(Sheetname)` which is throwing the error? To be sure you could break it into 2 lines. Declare a workbook variable, say `wb` then in one line have `Set wb = Workbooks(PrintWB)` and in the next line have `wb.Sheets(SheetName).etc.` See which line triggers the error.

Comment: @JohnColeman We know `.Sheets(Sheetname)` isn't throwing the error because `PrintWB` in `Workbooks(PrintWB)` is the entire file path, which isn't an accepted format for `Workbooks()`. `Workbooks()` Is looking for either an INDEX number or the files name. In his case, the file name would be `"Master Test Sheet.xlsx"`.

Comment: @Tyeler Good point. I missed that detail. Still, it isn't a bad idea to break such things into 2 lines, partially for debugging reasons and partially for general design.

Comment: @JohnColeman I completely agree with you. In my answer I ended up doing something like that because I needed the workbooks name for the code to work the way he expects it to

Comment: @Tyeler Nice answer, bye the way. +1

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're having is that you're trying to print a workbook that Excel can't see. `Workbooks()` is a collection of all *open* workbooks.

Step 1 is opening the target workbook. Before we just open it though, it's always best to check that the file path is accurate. A simple `IF STATEMENT` will suffice: `If Dir(yourfilepath) <> "" Then`

Step 2 is to open the target workbook, print the target sheet, and then close the workbook. I added the line `Workbooks(targetworkbook).Saved = True`. This will hide the "Do you want to save your changes?" Dialog that pops up when we try to close the workbook. We know we didn't make any changes, so using this method is safe.

```
WBPath = .Cells(i, 1) & "\" & .Cells(i, 2)
PrintWB = .Cells(i,2) 'I'm assuming this is "Master Test Sheet.xlsx"
If Dir(WBPath) <> "" Then
    Workbooks.Open (WBPath)
    Workbooks(PrintWB).Sheets(Sheetname).PrintOut From:=1, To:=1
    Workbooks(PrintWB).Saved = True
    Workbooks(PrintWB).Close
Else: MsgBox "File not found.", vbCritical
End If
```

Comment: If this answers your question, would you mind marking this as the answer? Glad I could help!